# Should i use multiple firebase projects for different customers but the same app or only one for FCM?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to add push notification to my app with Firebase Cloud Messaging but i don't know the right way to set this up.

My app looks like this:
I have multiple customers (companies) who host their own server with a database for their employees.

Every employee of my customers will download the app to receive push notifications from their company's server which implements the firebase admin sdk to send push notifications.

I thought the easiest way would be to let every customer set up their own fcm project and then add the api key to the app. 
This is easy to set up in android, but in ios every company would need an apple dev account for the certificates which costs them 99€ every year just too receive push notifications.

So maybe only i need to set up one firebase project myself and generate a server key for every customer. This way only i need a apple dev account.

Is it possible to let every customer send push notifications through my fcm project to their employees but not to any other employees of different customers. They should not be allowed to see any data of other customers or send messages to them.

What's the intended way to set this up and is there a limit to push notifications in one firebase account? If only i host a fcm project for every customer i might hit the limit.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> They should not be allowed to see any data of other customers or send messages to them.

If you require isolation between customers, then they should definitely **not** be using the same project.  They should be in different projects, so they can't send messages outside of their own user base.

Answer (score 0):

According to Firebase documentation:

> For example, if you develop a white-label application, each independently labeled app should have its own Firebase project, and the iOS and Android versions of that label should be in the same Firebase project. Each independently labeled app shouldn't (for privacy reasons) share data with the others.

You can read more about it here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects

I would recommend using different project per customer in order to isolate between the accounts.