# Is it possible using one firebase project api key and sender id to many apps?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

If i have 50 android apps and create one Firebase project.

And can I collect user tokens from multiple apps with one google-services.json file and then send a cloud message?

In what units is it recommended to create a Firebase project?

I must created firebase project each android application??

Comment: This is recommended to use a project only for a single group of apps.

Answer (score 1):

*firebaser here*

Firebase recommend creating a separate project for each separate "logo".

So if you have multiple variants of the same app (i.e. pro vs lite, multiple languages, admin vs regular), you should put those in the same project (unless  you have a stringent reason to not do that).

If your multiple apps are of a different type, you should put them in separate projects (unless  you have a stringent reason to not do that).

Also see:

- [Can i use only one Firebase Project for many white-labeled apps? What is the best practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71106095/can-i-use-only-one-firebase-project-for-many-white-labeled-apps-what-is-the-bes)
- [How many of my clients apps could I manage on Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62702029/how-many-of-my-clients-apps-could-i-manage-on-firebase)
- [Should i use multiple firebase projects for different customers but the same app or only one for FCM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62001562/should-i-use-multiple-firebase-projects-for-different-customers-but-the-same-app)
- [Firebase project notifications with multiple applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57955290/firebase-project-notifications-with-multiple-applications)